# ubuntu 14.04 LTS install freezes (legacy boot, dell t7910)

Tags: ubuntu, boot, usb, ubuntu-14.04

We have a new dell desktop which came with 12.04 preinstalled and that works.
We are trying to replace 12.04 by 14.04.

For some reason, we really want to install in legacy mode (will patch the kernel with xenomai later on).

We created with disk creator a usb key with ubuntu 14.04 LTS desktop 64bits.
After booting the machine, we go to the boot menu (f12) then select usb in the legacy menu.

The screen goes black, then shows at the bottom the logo with the little guy in a circle, then the screen changes and shows "ubuntu" under which white/orange dots are displayed.
After a while, all green dots are orange. And things freeze there.

We tried to press "down arrow" at time the logo with the little guy in the circle is displayed, which allowed us to get to some menu that allowed us to try to boot in nomodeset. That did not help (keep freezing at the same stage).

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was a good idea to try to boot using the nomodeset option.
Seems like selecting "nomodeset" in the menu does not do the job (would that be a bug ?).

I saw that the menu was showing the boot option as a string that could be edited manually. Pressing "f6" and selecting "nomodeset" does not change that string. So I manually removed "quiet splash" and added "nomodeset", pressed enter, and yop yop, things went forward.